# Converting infix to postfix, do I need precendence table if I have brackets

Tags: java, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I have seen some code samples which convert infix to postix expressions which include precedence table for operator, as well as have logic for parsing braces.
Here is my point.

If braces are part of input then we dont need precendence table, while converting infix to postfix. In other words we need precendence table `iff` braces are not part of input.

Am I correct ?

Comment: If braces are part of the input they are used to *override* the normal operator precedence. You need both in infix notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the infix expression is fully parenthesized, then no, you don't need a precedence table.

Answer (score 1):

> If braces are part of input then we dont need precendence table, while converting infix to postfix. In other words we need precendence table iff braces are not part of input.

That's only true if the input expression is fully parenthesised according to the desired precedence. You can't assume that. Implementing precedence isn't so difficult that you should be looking for excuses to omit it. See [here](/questions/19721072/handling-parenthesis-while-converting-infix-expressions-to-postfix-expresssions) for how.